# Work around for extracting date using js and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing, date

I'm working with 2 programs and have to use a work around because they aren't compatible.  In one platform I'm using a date picker, which when you pick a date pulls date selected into a string format like this.  9/8/2011 12:00:00 AM.  I need to be parse out the date by itself into a new string to display (09/08/2011) mm/dd/yyyy using javascript/c# but am drawing a blank.

I've come up with something aling these lines, but it doesn't seem to work and I'm grasping at straws at the end of the day.

```
function OnDateSelected(sender, e) {
    var str = document.getElementById("REQ_ER_DATE_PICK_PLACEHOLDER").Text = REQ_ER_DATE_PICK.SelectedDate.ToString();
    var trimmed = str.Split(' ')[0].Trim();
    var x = DateTime.Parse(trimmed);

    document.getElementById("REQ_ER_DATE_PICK_PLACEHOLDER").Text = str; 

}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use external libraries to solve your problem you should look into http://www.datejs.com/

It allows you to parse various string formats into javascript date objects. I really love the library and use it whenever I need to mess with dates and what not.

For your problem specifically you would just use this:

```
var new_date = Date.parse('9/8/2011 12:00:00 AM');
new_date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```